# How to compare two date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have three dates: (1) previousDate (2) currentDate (3) nextDate,
I want to check whether currentDate is later then previous date and earlier than nextDate.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

```
 NSDateFormatter *df= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *dt1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSDate *dt2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dt1=[df dateFromString:@"2011-02-25"];

dt2=[df dateFromString:@"2011-03-25"];

NSComparisonResult result = [dt1 compare:dt2];

switch (result)

{

     case NSOrderedAscending: NSLog(@"%@ is greater than %@", dt2, dt1); break;

     case NSOrderedDescending: NSLog(@"%@ is less %@", dt2, dt1); break;

     case NSOrderedSame: NSLog(@"%@ is equal to %@", dt2, dt1); break;

     default: NSLog(@"erorr dates %@, %@", dt2, dt1); break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you're using the [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

You can use [isEqualToDate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate:) to compare two NSDate objects. And also the [earlierDate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/earlierDate:) and [laterDate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/laterDate:) to check currentdate is bigger than previous date and smaller than next date.

Answer (score 4):

I simply used this to check it:

```
if ([[currentDate laterDate:nextDate] isEqualToDate:nextDate]) {
    NSLog(@"currentDate is earlier than nextDate");
}
if ([[currentDate laterDate:previousDate] isEqualToDate:currentDate]) {
    NSLog(@"currentDate is later then previousDate");
}
```

worked fine for me! Thx @Luca Matteis for the hint "laterDate:"

Answer (score 2):

We can compare two dates easily in swift 5.0

```
    switch dateOld.compare(dateNew) {
    case .orderedAscending:
        // Put your code for greater
        break

    case .orderedDescending:
        // Put your code less
        break;

    case .orderedSame:
        // Put your code for equal
        break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSDate objects also implement well-documented -compare: method.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform two comparisons using the `compare` message of `NSDate`:

```
if ([previousDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedAscending &&
    [nextDate compare:currentDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"current date is in between previous and next date (non-inclusive)");
}
```