# Sort Array of Dictionaries by NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an array of dictionaries. Within each dictionary, there is a a key `dateOfInfo` (an `NSDate`) and several other things. I want to sort the array by each dictionaries `dateOfInfo` with the most recent being the first result.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can sort using `NSSortDescription`, e.g.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"dateOfInfo" ascending: NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

You can also use the method

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))comparator context:(void *)context
```

Comment: This is just about perfect. I used the first part of your code but had to change the Ascending to NO and instead of sortUsingDescriptors I had to use sortedArrayUsingDescriptors. Other than that, this worked wonderfully. Thanks yet again, PengOne!

Comment: @James: Glad it worked. I updated my answer to incorporate your revisions.

Comment: I have array of dictionaries and I am sorting by age and bank number, but its not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

The basic bubble sorting algorithm would work. In this case you need to loop through your array, use valueForKey message on [array objectAtIndex:] to get the NSDate values. For comparing dates see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent) . So if you are sorting in ascending order of date, just add the object with the lower date (remember bubble sort comparisons?) to an array which will hold your sorted result.

Comment: Thanks for the link to that post. Working on it now.

Comment: The second answer is easier too using a NSSortDescriptor. But the way my brain went on this shows one thing. I'm still an algorithms and C guy. Throwing fancy classes at me still doesn't work :)

Comment: `NSArray` has a lot of powerful built-in sorting functionality; there's no need to do this by hand.

Comment: And to the person who downvoted this: A downvote is for an answer that isn't useful. Hope you knew the meaning of that sentence. The answer isn't wrong or useless. Just that there exists an easier way using NSSortDescriptor

Comment: I was able to get it to work this way, but I replaced it with PengOne's code because it was quite a bit shorter and much faster. Thank you though! :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
            NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
             [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
             NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
             {
                 NSDate *date1 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string1];
                 NSDate *date2 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string2];

                 return [date1 compare:date2];
             };
             NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"StartTime" ascending:YES comparator:compareDates];
             [youArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc1]];
```