# Compare two NSDates in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, comparison, nsdate

I am new to iPhone developer,

i want to compare two Dates, first date will come from Database let say, `newDate` and second is todays date,

if today is greater then `newDate` then i want to display alert.

Here is my code snippet,

```
NSString *newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:st];
NSDate *today=[[NSDate alloc]init];

if ([today compare:newDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
{
    NSLog(@"today is later than newDate");        
}
else if ([today compare:newDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
{
    NSLog(@"today is earlier than newDate");        
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");        
}
```

but it crashes, and while compiling it also shows me warning here `[today compare:newDate]`

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: This should help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent

Comment: What does the warning say for `[today compare:newDate]` ? Perhaps that warning should give you a clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you are comparing strings and dates. If you look at `newDate`, you will see that its a `NSString` and not a `NSDate`. If you use the `compare:` method on `NSDate`, both objects have to be `NSDate`'s. Looking at your code, it looks like `st` is the `NSDate` corresponding to `newDate` (although your naming seems a bit odd), try `today` with it instead of `newDate`

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to compare a date object with a string. You need to compare to date object.

```
[today compare:newDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
```

`newDate` should be a NSDate instance. I have done this and its working.