# formatting date issue returning Nil all the time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a `NSDate *da` and when i print i get the following string : `2013-10-24 00:00:00 +0000`.

```
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSDate *myD = [form dateFromString: @"2013-10-24"];
```

Now what i want to do is to compare `NSDate *da` and `NSDate *myD`. If it matches i need to print a `NSLog`.

```
if ([da isEqualToDate:myD]) {    
    NSLog(@"ok");               
} else {
    NSLog(@"bad");
}
```

The problem is that `myD` becomes `null`. How can i solve this?

UPDATE

Still there's a problem with the formatter; However now it doesn't return NIL.

When i print `da` i get the output `2013-10-24 13:00:00 +0000` and when i print `myD` i get the output `2013-10-23 18:30:00 +0000`. Why didn't this get format correctly. I think there still exist some error in the formatting part of my code. Help

**UPDATE 2**

```
NSDate *da = [NSDate date]; ///// PRINTS 2013-09-16 11:52:40 +0000

    NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *myD = [form dateFromString: @"2013-09-16"]; ////// PRINTS 2013-09-16 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412852/compare-two-nsdates-in-iphone

Comment: Paste a whole code how you create both dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns incorrect date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273001/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-incorrect-date)

Comment: Have you ever heard of a "time zone"???

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is wrong as 'mm' stands for minutes, not months. Correct format will be

```
[form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Comment: There tend to be some error in the formatting part of my code. Can you please have a look, i have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Month should be in uppercase:

```
[form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

`NSDateFormatter` uses the specifications detailed [here](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: I am still having a problem with the formatting. I have edited my Question. Help

Comment: @sharonHwk It's a timezone issue; search for that and you should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your dateformatter like

```
 [form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

and You can compare like this..

```
 NSTimeInterval daInterval = [da timeIntervalSince1970];
 NSTimeInterval myDInterval = [myD timeIntervalSince1970];

 if(daInterval == myDInterval)
    NSLog(@"dates are same..");
```

Comment: Question is not how to compare `NSDate` instances, but `NSDateFormatter` returning `nil` for date format.

Comment: You can edit your answer to improve it and I will remove the down-vote.

Comment: I have edited my post, there still exist a problem in the formatting. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is that you are not doing this:

```
[form setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

And you create a time in different timezone and than it gets formatted to your local timezone while printing.

Comment: I have updated my question, there seems to be an error in the code.

Comment: Please read my answer - you don't need formatting for comparation of dates - that's really wrooong way to do that.

Comment: I tried your code but its still the same. I think it's comparing the time as well `13:00:00 +0000` and `18:30:00 +0000`. therefore how should i get rid of it.

Comment: Can you update question with the code of how you create the second date and what you expect there ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *str1=@"2013-10-24 00:00:00 +0000";
    NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [form setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
    NSDate *date1= [form dateFromString:str1];
    NSLog(@"%@",date1);


    NSString *str2=@"2013-10-24 00:00:00 +0000";
    NSDate *date2= [form dateFromString:str2];

   if ([date1 isEqualToDate:date2]) {
      NSLog(@"Same");
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"Not Same");
  }
```

i hope it is useful..