# Comparing two NSDates that are in different time zones

Tags: cocoa, timezone, nsdate

I have two dates, one is in the UTC timezone and the other is in New Zealand. I need to compare if one date is greater than the other.

How do I do this? Do I need to convert them to the same timezone first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDate`s don't have timezones. They represent absolute moments in time. As long as you made the `NSDate`s correctly -- i.e., if you created them via an `NSDateFormatter`, *it* has a timezone that needs to be set -- you can compare them directly.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can just compare them with the NSDate comparison function, which returns ascending/descending (kind of crazy semantics, but works).

[How to compare two NSDates: Which is more recent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent)