# How can i compare two dates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I am trying to compare two dates whether which one is the new or old, my dates are in following format:

> 2013-06-03 09:30:35

(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

Please give me some ideas, both are currently in string format?

So is that possible to convert ad check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

**NSString to NSDate**

```
NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
// if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];
```

**NSDate convert to NSString:**

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@", strDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Please read this

[enter link description here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-earlierDate_)

```
if ([yourFirstDate compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"yourFirstDate is later than secondDate");        

} else if ([yourFirstDate compare:secondDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"yourFirstDate is earlier than secondDate");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

**same as @DIVYU 's  Link**

Comment: You left out the bit about comparisons.

Comment: thanks but how can i compare?

Comment: ok great work.let me try this

Comment: If it's the same as the duplicate link, then just mark the question as a duplicate. It's the way this site is supposed to work. Duplicate questions just make it harder to have proper answers to proper questions.

Answer (score 2):

Convert that strings into `NSDate` using `dateFormatter`.
You can check this link Here is good discussion of your problem
[How to compare two NSDates: Which is more recent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent)

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate, please mark it is a duplicate rather than answering with a link to the other question and answer.

Comment: Okay but i don't see any option to mark duplicate.

Comment: It's under the link for closing. It gives you options for why you are recommending closure. One of the reasons is that it is a duplicate. You can paste the link to the duplicate in there.

Comment: @user2439088: Give respect to others.... Abizern helps you

Comment: @AnoopVaidya  i respect you , Abizern  sorry for that comment