# iOS: Compare two less or equal NSDates

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to compare two dates and do something when one is less or equal than the other, I tried to do it this way:

```
if ([self.system.systemInbetriebnahme compare:date] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return nil;
```

But this removes the case when they are both equal is there a way to compare dates with `>=` ?

Thank you

**More details:**  I have a date taken from a double dimension array, and i have a date stored in core data(through date picker), and i go through a loop to compare the two dates with the rule that: Date in array must be greater or equal than input date stored in database.

**Latest Edit:**

- I import a csv file which after parsing and formatting gives me two rows(one for number value and one for dates). Here I am interested in dates.
- I store all these in an array and save after checking consistency of the data in this function:

  ```
  for (NSArray * row in array) {


   // Handle import if there are at least two rows


  if (row.count > 1) {

              dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                  // Try to import value,date formatted row
                  double value = [row[0] doubleValue];
                  NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:row[1]];
                 //else {

                      // Try to import date,value row

                      if (date && value != 0.0) {
                          [self addReading:value forDate:date];
                      }
  ```
- In here i call the function `addreading` to check for errors for some rules and if everything is okey then i save the managedObject Context.

  ```
   if ([installationdatum compare:date] != NSOrderedAscending)
                 { 
                 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                   message:@"installation date is bigger than data"
                                                                    delegate: nil
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                           otherButtonTitles:nil] 

                      [alert show];
                     return nil;



                 } else
                 {  //Do nothing

                 }
  ```
- One rule for me is to get the first row element in the array and compare its date with an input stored already in the database which is the `self.system.systemInbetriebnahme`
- After all this I list all the resulting array in a tableview, though value matching `NSOrderedSame` is never shown when it is equal to `self.system.systemInbetriebnahme`

Comment: You could get thousands of link for the same, why dont you search SO before posting the ques?

Comment: because it does not answer the question about date comparison simulating operator >=.

Comment: please look at the edit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply check for not ascending order.

```
if ([self.system.systemInbetriebnahme compare:date] != NSOrderedAscending)
        return nil;
```

Comment: what does not ascending order imply in logical expression?

Comment: It implies either `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`

Comment: There are only three valid values for the enum - `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame`. So not being ascending means it is same or descending.

Comment: I understand, I tried but it still ignores the value at NSOrderedSame. I dont know why

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by ignore? Are you sure the two dates are absolutely the same?

Comment: I have a date taken from a double dimension array, and i have a date stored in core data(through date picker), and i go through a loop to compare the two dates with the rule that: Date in array must be greater or equal than input date stored in database.

Comment: Can you edit your question with more code and details?

Comment: okey will do, please recheck

Answer (score 12):

Simple...

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");        

} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");

} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");

}
```

Comment: Copy&pasted from [the answer of a different person](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965106/400056) without attribution. Please do not do that.

Comment: @DarkDust:  Yes it was copied to my code(project) before this question, Later I searched for the link, I didn't get so . I copied from my code n added here.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *toDay = [[NSDate alloc]init];

NSLog(@"%@",toDay);

 NSLog(@"%@",yourSecondDate);

if ([toDay timeIntervalSinceDate:yourSecondDate] < 30.0f) 
 {
    NSLog(@"Do Something");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well >= just means that they are !<, so you can check

```
if ([self.system.systemInbetriebnahme compare:date] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Comment: what you wrote implies : == NSOrderedDescending, which does not account when both dates can be equal.

Comment: It doesn't imply that. You're missing the third case, `NSOrderedSame`. This answer does what you want

Comment: I thought it would but, it still does not take into account the case when NSOrderedSame is true :(

Comment: Yes it does. If it is NOT NSOrderedAscending, then it is either NSOrderedDescending or NSOrderedSame, just like @Gabriele said

Answer (score 1):

You could either check if the result is equal to both `NSOrderedDescending` and  `NSOrderedSame`:

```
NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [self.system.systemInbetriebnahme compare:date]
if (comparisonResult == NSOrderedDescending  || comparisonResult == NSOrderedSame)
        return nil;
```

Or just not match the one option left:

```
NSComparisonResult comparisonResult = [self.system.systemInbetriebnahme compare:date]
if (comparisonResult != NSOrderedAscending)
        return nil;
```

In your case I would go the later option, since you only have 3 options check against the one you don't want is easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you. `do something when one is less or equal than the other as you` looking different case.

```
switch ([self.system.systemInbetriebnahme compare: date]) {
case NSOrderedAscending:
    // system date earlier then date
    break;
case NSOrderedSame:
    //  Same
    break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
    // system date later then date
    break;
}
```

Comment: I really thought it would be the answer, but it still removes the value when the case NSOrderedSame is true.

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct comparision like >= but you can do it like this

```
NSComparisonResult compareStart = [date1 compare: selectedDate]; // date1 is 6/6/2011 00:00
NSComparisonResult compareEnd = [date2 compare: selectedDate];   // date2 is 9/6/2011 00:00

if ((compareStart == NSOrderedAscending) || (compareStart == NSOrderedSame)
&& (compareEnd == NSOrderedDescending))
{
// date is in the right range
}
```

or you simply compare

```
if ((compareStart == NSOrderedAscending) )
{
// date is in the right range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To com[are two `NSDate`, this :

```
[[date1 earlierDate:date2] isEqualToDate: date1]
```

returns `YES` if the date1 is earlier than date2.

**EDIT**

if you want date1 >= date2 (later or equals to) use this condition :

```
([[date1 laterDate:date2] isEqualToDate: date1] || [date2 isEqualToDate:date1])
```

Comment: But with a minimum search in the Apple documentation, you would not have to post such a question...

Comment: I am asking specificly about >= for NSDates.  There was no mention in it in the app doc or results given by stackoverflow search, so I wanted to ask here. Thank you.