# Comparison of two identical NSDates returning unequal outcome

Tags: ios, nsdate

I am comparing two NSDates called `serverDate` and `localDate`. Despite both dates outputting to be the same time, I continue to get that `serverDate` is show to be more recent than `localDate`.

Here is my code for comparison:

```
if ([serverDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] > [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) {
        NSLog(@"server date more recent");

    } else if ([serverDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] <= [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]){
        NSLog(@"local date more recent");

    }
```

I have used extremely precise `NSDateFormatter` to display the date as `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSSSSSSSSSZ"`, which outputs the following: `Server date: 2014-09-17 23:20:02:5090000000-0700, local date: 2014-09-17 23:20:02:5090000000-0700`. But even then, `serverDate` continue to be regarded as the more recent date.

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks for your input.

Comment: `NSLog(@"%f, %f", [serverDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])` What would you get when you log it out.

Comment: Good call @KudoCC! When I log it out I get `432714002.509000, 432714002.508961` for the two dates respectively. I guess if there is a way that I could round the nearest 1/10 of a second would be the best solution.

Comment: You also don't need `else if` as `else` will have the same effect.

Comment: True that about the `else if`. Will change in code.

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465502/ios-compare-two-less-or-equal-nsdates/18465596#18465596

Comment: I'm curious to know what is the result if you use `[serverDate compare:localDate]` or `[serverDate timeIntervalSinceDate:localDate]` to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `NSimeIntervell` as `NSDate` Has `Compare` Function for comparing dates  use `compare` function instead

```
if ([serverDate  compare:localDate ] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"serverDate is later than localDate");
} else if ([serverDate  compare:localDate] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"serverDate is earlier than localDate");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If [this](https://code.google.com/p/cocotron/source/browse/Foundation/NSDate/NSDate.m?r=83f4dcd06e67963108a3ee0f9942a6609ad35edf) is anything to go by, `NSDate` uses the `NSTimeInterval` for comparison anyway.

Comment: Agree but why not use something that iOS provides as property.

Comment: I don't disagree; my comment was for interest only.

Answer (score 1):

This will  help you  it works for me

```
if ([serverDate isEqualToDate: localDate])
    {
        NSLog(@"Date are same");
    }else
{
 NSLog(@"Date are not equal")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your answer. While `isEqualToDate` is great, what I would really like to be able to tell is whether if one date is later than the other date. I guess using `>` or `<` would not be ideal here?

Comment: this will help you 
if ([serverDate compare:localDate] == -1)
    {
        NSLog(@"serverDate is later than localDate");
    } else if ([serverDate compare:localDate] == 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"serverDate is earlier than localDate");
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"dates are the same");
    }