# Comparing Date and Time Object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was working with a method and it was not giving me proper output then I came to know, the way I was comparing date and time object was completely wrong. I googled but could not find some relevant solution. I want to compare a date and time object with another object.

for example:

```
  if (dtcur >= dtstart && dtcur <= myDT) // 2014-03-24 11:30:00 >= 2014-03-24 11:00:00 & 2014-03-24 11:30:00 <= 2014-03-25 11:00:00
  {
     // should come here in if condition
  }
```

but it goes in else. It means my comparison is wrong, can anyone help me about how to compare two date and time objects. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent). This may help you

Comment: isn't it only for date comparison ? I want to compare date and time with another date an time for example if(dateTimeObj1 <=dateTimeObj2)
{
   nslog (@"yes");
}
where as dateAndTimeObj1 would be 2014-05-2014 12:31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many objects, including NSDate, have a `compare:` method. Use it like so:

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
  // date2 is after date1
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
  // date2 is before date1
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame) {
  // they're both the same date
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't solve the issue. Read the question carefully before typing anything in the answers.

Comment: @IgorMatyushkin Hmm? He wants to know how to compare dates. That's what my code does.

Comment: it had worked P.s. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL isLaterOrEqualToStartDate = [dtcur isEqualToDate:dtstart] || [dtcur later:dtstart];
BOOL isEarlierOrEqualToMyDate = [dtcur isEqualToDate:myDT] || [dtcur earlier:myDT];

if(isLaterOrEqualToStartDate && isEarlierOrEqualToMyDate)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you refering to NSDate ?? if so you can compare using the property timeIntervalSince1970  (which is a double value). you cannot directly compare NSDate as they are objects. Here is small example. you can uncomment the line to see how result changes .

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [date1 dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];

if (date2.timeIntervalSince1970 > date1.timeIntervalSince1970)
{
 NSLog(@"date 2 is bigger");
}
else
{
NSLog(@"date 1 is bigger");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not possible to compare two NSDate objects? Why don't you read Apple's documentation before writing such wrong things?

Comment: why dont you try to understand the context of what I said before typing such nonsense ? 

if you compare nsobjects with ( > , < , >= , <= ) you will get undesired results. run it for yourself (several times) and see if you're so sure it works... NSDate has a compare: method which you can use otherwise easiest would be to use the method timeIntervalSince1970 which will give you a double value which you can compare the way he intended.

Comment: hey @nsuinteger, you've mistaken with receiver of this message. I never compared NSDate objects with primitive operators. And your solution of using `compare:` method is not the best in kind of performance. Use `later:` and `earlier:` methods instead.

Comment: Your code doesn't solve the issue.