# Time comparisons in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Question:

I need to compare 2 times - the current time and a set one. If the set time is in the future, find out how many minutes remain until said future time.

Other Info:

I am currently using

```
let date = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
let hour = components.hour
let minutes = components.minute
```

which I stole from another answer on SO about how to get the current time in Int format. I then split the future time into hour (Int) and minutes(Int) and compare those... But that gets odd when you go over the hour barrier.

Comment: See...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent and the first comment on that question..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have compare function to compare 2 NSDate to know which one is more recent. It returns NSCompareResults

```
enum NSComparisonResult : Int {
    case OrderedAscending
    case OrderedSame
    case OrderedDescending
}
```

Get distance (in seconds) from 2 NSDate, you have .timeIntervalSinceDate(). Then, you know how to convert to minutes, hours, ...

```
let date1 : NSDate = ... 
let date2 : NSDate = ...

let compareResult = date1.compare(date2)

let interval = date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2)
```

Answer (score 10):

just to add to @tyt_g207's answer, I found the compare method, but hadn't found `NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending` and the others. I used something like the modified below to check an expiration date against today's date

```
let date1 : NSDate = expirationDate 
let date2 : NSDate = NSDate() //initialized by default with the current date

let compareResult = date1.compare(date2)
if compareResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
    println("\(date1) is later than \(date2)")
}

let interval = date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(date2)
```

Comment: Is this all in UTC? What about comparing local times ?

Answer (score 5):

```
    let dateComparisionResult: NSComparisonResult = currentDate.compare("Your Date")


    if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    {
        // Current date is smaller than end date.
    }
    else if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending
    {
        // Current date is greater than end date.

    }
    else if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame
    {
        // Current date and end date are same.

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `timeIntervalSinceDate` of date on further date and pass the earlier date as parameter, this would give the time difference