# Calculating time difference using a colon

Tags: swift, date

Im trying to calculate the time difference between 18:00 & 06:00 and display the result in the same format. Both times are entered manually.

Comment: can you show us the code you've tried?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316521/time-comparisons-in-swift

Comment: Hi Steve the times art NSDate they are entered manually.

Comment: you can create an NSDate from your input strings and then do the compare.

Answer (score 1):

First create two NSDates from the string inputs and get the interval between the two then pass the interval through a formatting function we will create:

```
let date1:String = "12:00"
let date2:String = "13:00"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
let date3 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date1)
let date4 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2)

let interval = date4!.timeIntervalSinceDate(date3!)
print("\(stringFromTimeInterval(interval))")
```

now we need to format the interval which is the number of seconds between the two so create a function which returns a string:

```
func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
  let interval = Int(interval)
  let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
  let hours = (interval / 3600)
  return String(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes)
}
```

in your case you will set the date1 and date2 from I'm guessing the text fields in your program.

Comment: The above code worked.

Comment: How do I save the data i.e. time difference, once displayed, I am now using NSDate format.

Comment: how would you like to save it? are you on a mac or iOS device?  is this the only number you are saving?  This is a big discussion there are many ways.  If you are just saving a single number and are on an iOS device do a google search for NSUserDefaults.

Comment: My ambition is to build a time sheet, saving start time, finish time less breaks. I have every thing laid out and having issues saving the time difference. On iOS device.

Comment: is this for one device or multiple devices to the same place? it sounds to me you want this for multiple users to the same place.  If that is the case look into backend services like firebase or backand

Comment: Im using it for personal use so theres no need for multiple device settings.

Comment: Ok then just use nsuserdefaults.