# Calculate days between two days errror objective c

Tags: objective-c, date

hello i am trying to calculate days between today and past date 10-05-2015 in objective c. but when i put condition as follows it always going in if condition. what should be the problem in my code?

```
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy hh:mm a"];

    NSDate *Startdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    Startdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:eventstartdate];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful

    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy hh:mm a"];
    NSDate *CurrentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    CurrentDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:Currentdate];

    NSDate *startDate= Startdate;
    NSDate *endDate = CurrentDate ;
    if ([CurrentDate earlierDate:Startdate])
    {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *differenceComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
        NSInteger numDays = differenceComponents.day;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *AlertMsg =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Event is scheduled at %@",eventstartdate] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [AlertMsg show];
    }
```

get same type of date format as 2015-05-21 12:00 for startdate and end date besides the i have given different formats.

is there any problem with my code?

Comment: have you read the documentation on `earlierDate:` ? It seems not. It returns the earlier date of the two... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965044/how-to-compare-two-nsdates-which-is-more-recent for various ways of solving your problem

Comment: thanks volker. i haven't read yet.

Comment: find solution : if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
} else if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
} else {
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Docs of  [Apple : `NSDate compare:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:)

> Returns an NSComparisonResult value that indicates the temporal ordering of the receiver and another given date.
>
> `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate`
>
> **Parameters** `anotherDate`
>
> The date with which to compare the
>   receiver. This value must not be nil.
>   If the value is nil, the behavior is
>   undefined and may change in future
>   versions of Mac OS X.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> If:
>
> The receiver and anotherDate are
>   exactly equal to each other,
>   **`NSOrderedSame`**
>
> The receiver is later in
>   time than anotherDate,
>   **`NSOrderedDescending`**
>
> The receiver is
>   earlier in time than anotherDate,
>   **`NSOrderedAscending`**

In other words:

**If you want to check for same date**

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedSame) 
{
    NSLog(@"dates are the same");
}
```

**If you want to check for later date**

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedDescending) 
{
     NSLog(@"date1 is later than date2");
}
```

**If you want to check for earlier date**

```
if ([date1 compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending) 
{
    NSLog(@"date1 is earlier than date2");
}
```